# Что логировать в методе

Tags: c#, логирование

У меня есть некий класс-сервис. Я хотел бы обвешать его логами на все случаи жизни. Примерно так:

```
public class MyService 
{
    private readonly MyCache _cache;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly Ilog _log;

    public MyService(IRepository reposotory, MyCache cache, Ilog log)
    {
        _repository = reposotory;
        _cache = cache;
        _log = log;
    }

    public FooViewModel GetFoo(int fooId)
    {
        _log.Info("вызван метод GetFoo. fooId = {0}", fooId);
        try
        {
            string cacheKey = String.Format("GetFoo_{0}", fooId);
            // операции с кэшем не логируем, это происходит внутри самого класса кэша
            FooViewModel res = _cache.Get<FooViewModel>(cacheKey);

            if (res != null) 
            {
                _log.Info("данные получены из кэша. fooId = {0}", fooId);
                return res;
            }
            Foo foo = Repository.AllFoo().First(x => x.Id == fooId);
            res = MyMapper.Map<Foo, FooViewModel>(foo)
            _cache.Add(cacheKey, res);
            _log.Info("данные получены из базы. fooId = {0}", fooId);
            return res.ToArray();
        }
        catch (DatabaseException ex)
        {
            // здесь ничего не логируем, так как выбрасываем исключение вверх,
            // где и будет всё записано в лог
            throw new FooException(ex, "Какое-то сообщение");
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос: что тут вообще стоило бы логировать, а что нет? Правильно ли я расставил вызовы логера?

Comment: Логгер просто облегчает дебаггинг кода и нужно логгировать лишь то, что необходимо. В разных ситуациях по разному. Иногда достаточно знать, что с такими то данными сервис выполнил свою задачу. Универсального совета нет.

Comment: На все случаи жизни всё обвешать логами не получится и это не нужно.
Про ваш конкретный случай. Представьте что ваш сервис работает для крупного инет магазина, который обслуживает миллионы запросов. Вы уверены, что хотите иметь информацию, о том, что ваш сервис вызывается миллион раз в день? И если представить, что логгирование ведется в БД, тогда в случае исключения вы как раз не увидите ничего полезного в вашем журнале.

Comment: Логируйте то, что вам нужно. Если не знаете что логировать - значит ничего и не надо логировать. Вот когда возникнет такая ситуация, что ошибка может быть поймана только логированием в определенном месте - тогда и добавите в это место логирование.

Comment: Repository.AllFoo().First(x => x.Id == fooId); - реализуйте в репозитории метод Find